# Restrict browsers to click button until checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, button

could someone show me a jquery rule wherein after a checkbox is checked, it will enable a button to be clicked to get to the next page/div. I have a one page sliding website. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#checkboxId').change(function(){
    $('#buttonId').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something as below :

```
$("#checkBoxID").click(function()
{
   $("#buttonID").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
   //or 
   $("#buttonID").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
});
```

use one of the above..

Comment: `attr` doesn't work with boolean values. Anyway you should use `prop` for those kind of tasks

Comment: you can try is(':checked'); btw make sure the code hides button when you click it off

Comment: @red-X. You can pass `XXXX` instead of `disabled` and it'll work, but that's not the way `attr` should be used.

Comment: @red-X. I checked the source code of jQuery, and I have no idea why nor how it works with `false`. I wouldn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it your if condition:

```
$('#checkBox').attr('checked');
```

or

```
$('#edit-checkbox-id').is(':checked');
```

Comment: `attr` is wrong here. it checks the initial state of the checkbox, not the current!

Comment: Well that was just tip not full answer, it will check if you bind it to change() for example. Thanks for conern tho.